# military grid refrence system geocode reverse

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, mgrs

I have lat/long and I get geocode like 34TCK9320739642 from mgrs geocode reverse in arcmap

how can convert that to address (country.city.state)

Comment: MGRS isn't really involved, just the lon/lat into a street address, so your question is just "How can I convert lon/lat into an address?"

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you would have to provide a little more information for a more detailed response.  If you are familiar with Python you can use the [mgrs library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs) to convert MGRS to Decimal Degrees and then use the [reverse geocode](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/geocoding-toolbox/reverse-geocode.htm#C_GUID-DC8D592F-64B0-45BF-95D6-9800C69CC1DF) tool to get the address.

mgrs usage:

```
import mgrs

m = mgrs.MGRS()
coords = m.toLatLon("34TCK9320739642")
```

output would be a tuple:

```
(40.1003016936209,19.74708817656555)
```

you will need [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/) and [Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) for the library to work.  I'm not sure what licence level you need in ArcMap to run the reverse geocoder but you will need an address locator.

This is my example of using the revese geocode tool:

The tool:

[image]

The input table:

[image]

The output table:

[image]

Comment: I have lat and long but I need conversion mgrs geocode reverse to address and given country . city ...

Comment: Like I said,  use the "Reverse Geocode" tool in ArcMap.  You will need to specify a locator in the tool and should create address fields in the new feature class it creates.  The big thing is to have a usable address locator.

Comment: yes true but I cant find free without IP reverse geocode or free address locator